# Is it possible to set up a custom domain for a community?

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community

We are trying to setup custom domain for a community. I wanted to know if we can set up a domain similar to https://abc.com/xyz.

Currently we have a live instance of https://abc.com and wanted to use https://abc.com/xyz to point at our new community build on Salesforce.

Is this something possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible [since Summer '14](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/communities_custom_domain_URL.htm).

The below text is extracted from [this article on Thinkaholics.com](https://www.thinkaholics.com/salesforce/how-to-add-a-custom-url-to-salesforce-communities/), and I'm copying the relevant bits here in case the blog isn't accessible in the future.

---

Setting up the custom URL and SSL certificate is relatively painless. You will need to do the following;

1. Add the custom URL to Salesforce
2. Generate a Certificate Signing Request from Salesforce
3. Create a CNAME (Alias) record in your domain name registrar
4. Generate an SSL certificate in your domain name registrar
5. Upload the SSL certificate to Salesforce

Custom domains are supported only in non-sandbox instances. You can configure a custom domain in a sandbox instance and then migrate it to a production instance, but the custom domain is only active in production.

Comment: Thanks Renato. We did setup the domain as mentioned in the doc ex: xyz.com and pointed to community url. What we are looking for is if we can configure the URL with a directory architecture https://abc.com/[directory]/[page-name]

Comment: That's a totally different question from what you described on your original question. You want to know if you can use custom, non-salesforce paths in your community (and I don't really know the answer).

Comment: Adding some more info. You can use Salesforce CDN to prevent any hassles with certificates. You will get a shared certificate. Also there's is a pilot to enable domains in sandboxes.